# Authenticate a user and get token without a password (PHP Admin SDK)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The scenario is that I need to perform a data import from an old MYSQL database over to AWS architecture.

My initial thought was that I can authenticate the user using the Admin SDK to authenticate the user, however, if the user exists in Cognito it means that I don't know the password to authenticate and then communicate with the other services.

Is there a way I can authenticate as the user to perform the import without knowing their password as the Cognito owner in PHP?

Comment: I guess this post may help you somehow
https://mauricius.dev/easily-impersonate-any-user-in-a-laravel-application/

Comment: @Farid Sorry but this not related to Cognito, I am aware of how to impersonate a Laravel User, but the issue is authenticating via Cognito, I can't find a way, as an admin, to impersonate a user within Cognito.

Comment: Ahhh my mistake, sorry I didn't catch the whole sense of your problem.